# Electric field inside conductor with a cavity

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

Suppose I have a neutral spherical conductor with a cavity inside. Suppose there's a $+q$ point charge inside the cavity.

I know that the electric field $\vec{E}$ is zero within the conductor, also know that there will be a $-q$ net charge in the inner surface of conductor with the cavity.

But I still don't understand if there can be an non-zero electric field **inside** the cavity due to $+q$.

Gauss law to a gaussian surface inside the cavity says it does:

$$
\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{A} = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0} \qquad \longrightarrow \qquad E \, A = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \, \frac{+q}{r^2},
$$

where $r$ is the distance from $+q$ to a point inside the cavity.

Is my reasoning right? I mean, the electric field is always zero **inside the conductor**, but there can be a non-zero electric field inside the cavity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the inner and outer radii of a spherical conductor with a cavity be $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively. The electric scalar potential distribution is given by the following equation.
\begin{equation}
\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0}{q}\phi(r) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{r}+\left(-\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)\;\;\;\text{(for }r<R_1 \text{)} \\
\frac{1}{R_2} \;\;\;\text{(for } R_1\leq r<R_2 \text{)} \\
\frac{1}{r} \;\;\;\text{(for } R_2\leq r \text{)}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Note that $\phi(r)$ is continuos at $r=R_1$ and $r=R_2$.
Electric field for this case is given as
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}=-\nabla\phi=
\begin{cases}
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2}\vec{e}_r\;\;\;\text{(for }r<R_1 \text{)} \\
0\vec{e}_r \;\;\;\text{(for } R_1\leq r<R_2 \text{)} \\
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2}\vec{e}_r \;\;\;\text{(for } R_2\leq r \text{)},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{e}_r$ is the unit vector.
As seen in this solution, what you wrote "the electric field is always zero inside the conductor, but there can be a non-zero electric field inside the cavity" is correct.