# How does screening reduce effective charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

Qualitatively, the running of coupling constant is often explained using a charge screening explanation such as that in the images below ([1](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/%7Ebiller/particle_course/Lectures/lecture_5.pdf) and [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0537)). It is said that the "bare" charge is not seen as it is shielded by polarized virtual electron-positron pairs, much like [a charge in a dielectric medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric-field_screening). Further, it is said that only probes closer to the central charge will see the "bare" charge or potential (c.f. the [Yukawa potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) where the potential is "most similar" to the unscreened Coulomb potential when the exponential is small near $r=0$).

[image: 1]

However, I am struggling to see why intuitively this is the case. Particularly, if the screen charge is view from far enough away, does it not tend to the fields of a  point charge (where all net neutral (electron-positron) dipoles average to zero field contribution leaving only the effect of the "bare" charge). If this is the case, it seems instead that the further from the charge you go, the less the screening has effect.

Additionally, using the second image (below) I cannot argue why the right hand charge would feel only a screened charge and not an increased effective charge, especially since the vacuum polarization seems to be moving point positive charges closer to the right hand charge (and closer to a $\frac{1}{r}$ singularity)!

[image]

Therefore, how can one intuitively explain how surrounding a point charges with (virtual) electron-positron pairs or dipoles (in a dielectric medium) should reduce the effective charge seen by an observer?

Answer (score 1):

To approach this topic, i considered a simple spherically symmetric problem of a classical  electrostatic field.
Because it is spherically symmetric, the equation is expressed in spherical coordinates.
Place the electric charge $+q$(C) at the centre. Place a dielectric sphere with an internal cavity around it. The inner radius of the dielectric sphere is $R_1$ and the outer radius is $R_2$.
[image: Charge surrounded by spherical dielectric]

The dielectric constant is given values and assumed to be as follows.
\begin{equation}
\epsilon(r)=
\begin{cases}
\epsilon_0\;\;\;\text{(for }r<R_1 \text{)}\\
\epsilon_r\epsilon_0\;\;\;\text{(for } R_1\leq r<R_2 \text{ and }\epsilon_r>1\text{)}\\
\epsilon_0\;\;\;\text{(for } R_2\leq r \text{)}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The electric scalar potential ($\phi$), the electric field ($\vec{E}$) and the electric flux density ($\vec{D}$) are expressed as,
\begin{equation}
\phi(r) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{r}-(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon_r})(\frac{1}{R1}-\frac{1}{R_2})\right)\;\;\;\text{(for } R_1\leq r<R_2{)}\\
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}(\frac{1}{\epsilon_rr}+(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon_r})\frac{1}{R_2})\;\;\;\text{(for } R_1\leq r<R_2) \\
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}\;\;\;\text{(for } R_2\leq r \text{)}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E_r(r) = -\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2}\;\;\;\text{(for } R_1\leq r<R_2{)}\\
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{\epsilon_rr^2}\;\;\;\text{(for } R_1\leq r<R_2) \\
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2}\;\;\;\text{(for } R_2\leq r \text{)}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D_r(r) = \epsilon(r)E_r(r)=\frac{q}{4\pi}
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{r^2}\;\;\;\text{(for }r<R_1 \text{)}\\
\frac{1}{r^2}\;\;\;\text{(for } R_1\leq r<R_2 \text{)}\\
\frac{1}{r^2}\;\;\;\text{(for } R_2\leq r \text{)}
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}
Note that $\phi(r)$ and $D_r(r)$ are continuous for $r=R_1$ and $r=R2$.

Assuming these equations are correct, there would be no effect outside the dielectric sphere to screen the electric charge +q(C) at the center.

Actually, I have considered the case of a conductor, not a dielectric.
[Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758903/electric-field-inside-conductor-with-a-cavity/758910#758910) is the formula for that. It still has no screening effect.

I vote against the claim that there is an electricity screening effect.

Comment: Consider the case of infinite dielectric medium with a spherical cavity, and place the charge in the center of the cavity. With calculations very similar to yours, one can get that field in the dielectric is smaller than the field in the cavity. This is exactly the screening effect which surely exists.

Comment: "I vote against the claim that there is an electricity screening effect." -- You may want to be a little careful with what you are voting on. [Vacuum polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization) in QED is quite well understood and leads to [an increase in the fine structure constant with energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Variation_with_energy_scale). I agree with you that the model you propose does not capture screening in QED, however. A model like @E.Anikin is describing does a better job mimicking how QED behaves, at a heuristic level.

Comment: @E.Anikin Is there an qualitative explanation of this screening?