# Electric field outside hollow disk filled with charged powder

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

If I contact electrify some dielectric powder, filter out the negatively charged part and fill it inside a hollow disk made of insulator material and seal it up, will there be an electric field around the disk?

I know Faraday cages don't, but they are metal. My question is about a faraday cage made of insulator material. Will this dissipate charge, if at all, any slower than a regular flat plate charged by rubbing and exposed to air?

The walls of the disk are very thin, like 0.2mm.

By "disk", I mean a very flat hollow cylinder made of insulator material, filled with negatively charged powder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently created two equations for the spherically symmetric case.
You can find them
[here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758903/electric-field-inside-conductor-with-a-cavity/758910#758910) and [there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/760222/how-does-screening-reduce-effective-charge/760260#760260).
Assuming these equations are correct, my conclusion is that if the sum of the internal electric chargess is not zero, then no matter whether it is a metal or an insulator, the internal electric charges cannot be shielded.
To be sure if I am right or not. I would like to wait for someone's rebuttal or criticism.

**EDIT: Addendum (appended on Apr 23 15:42:05 JST 2023)**

I cannot fully imagine what a hollow disk, as you call it, would look like.
So here I adopted the image of a plate with electric charged powder on it
and an insulator cover over the top.

In the case of a real geometry,
to obtain an approximation of what the physical quantities will be,
one must perform numerical calculations,
such as the finite element method, to find out.
However, even if the geometry in question seems relatively simple,
it requires a considerable amount of human work to perform numerical calculations,
so numerical calculations are avoided here.

As a simplified case of the first geometry,
i chose the spherically symmetric case(already explained this in the above lines.).
There we concluded that
there is no electrostatic shielding of the isolated electric charge.

As a second simplified case of the geometry, consider an one-dimensional model.
Suppose the real object is a dish with powder on it and the top part covered with an insulator.
In other words, the plate is very wide, and you have to think about the neighborhood of a part of it.
I believe that the following 1 dimensional model approximates the neighborhood of one part of the dish.
[image: 1D model]

As shown in the figure, $d$, $h_1$, and $H$ are the thicknesses of the insulation cover, charged powder, and dish, respectively.
$\epsilon_c$, $\epsilon_p$, and $\epsilon_d$ are the electric permitivities of the insulation cover, charged powder, and dish, respectively.
The $\epsilon_0$ is the electric permitivity of vacuum.

The electric scalar potential $\phi\;(V)$, the electcic field $\vec{E}\;(V/m)$ and the electric flux density $\vec{D}\;(C/m^2)$
are shown as follows after some manipulations.
\begin{equation}
\phi(z)=
\begin{cases}
(-\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_0})(z-h_1)+\frac{\rho h_1d}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}-\frac{1}{\epsilon_c}\right)\;\;\;\text{(for }h_1+d\leq z\text{)}\\
-\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_c}(z-h_1)\;\;\;\text{(for } h_1\leq z <h_1+d \text{)} \\
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_p}(z^2-h_1z) \;\;\;\text{(for } 0\leq z<h_1 \text{)} \\
(\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_d})z \;\;\;\text{(for } -H\leq z<0 \text{)} \\
(\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_0})z+\left\{(\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_0})-(\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_d})\right\}H \;\;\;\text{(for } z< -H \text{)},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left.\vec{E}\right|_z=-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_0} \;\;\;\text{(for }h_1+d\leq z\text{)} \\
\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_c} \;\;\;\text{(for } h_1\leq z <h_1+d \text{)} \\
\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_p}\left(z-\frac{h_1}{2}\right) \;\;\;\text{(for } 0\leq z<h_1 \text{)} \\
-\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_d} \;\;\;\text{(for } -H\leq z<0 \text{)} \\
-\frac{\rho h_1}{2\epsilon_0} \;\;\;\text{(for } z< -H \text{)},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left.\vec{D}\right|_z=\epsilon(z)\left.\vec{E}\right|_z=
\begin{cases}
\epsilon_0\vec{E}|_z=\frac{1}{2}\rho h_1\;\;\;\text{(for }h_1+d\leq z\text{)} \\
\epsilon_c\vec{E}|_z=\frac{1}{2}\rho h_1\;\;\;\text{(for } h_1\leq z <h_1+d \text{)} \\
\epsilon_p\vec{E}|_z
=\rho z-\frac{\rho h_1}{2}\;\;\;\text{(for } 0\leq r<h_1 \text{)} \\
\epsilon_d\vec{E}|_z=-\frac{1}{2}\rho h_1\;\;\;\text{(for } -H\leq z<0 \text{)} \\
\epsilon_0\vec{E}|_z=-\frac{1}{2}\rho h_1\;\;\;\text{(for } z< -H \text{)},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\rho\;(C/m^3)$ is the volume charge density.
These formulas are complicated by constants, but the formulas are linear and quadratic with respect to z, very simple.

The results of this one-dimensional calculation also indicate that electrostatic shielding does not occur again.

I suspect that the electric field produced by the electric charge is leaking out.

Comment: Appreciate the help. The equations are difficult for a beginner like me though :). Do you think that the charges will dissipate slower than if I charged a flat plat exposed to the air? I guess this too will have SOME air/moisture inside, but at least it should neutralize charge way slower?

Comment: @EL Flea, sorry I do not have the knowledge or experience to answer the item you are asking about in the comments section. What you are trying to do is interesting, so if you find something interesting, please post them in the form of a question to PSE.

Comment: Oops. That flat "plat" is actually flat plate. Probably got you hella confused :')

Comment: The item I'm asking about is a sealed hollow disk made of INSULATOR material, filled with charged powder. Will this charge leak out? There isn't much air inside the disk after filling it up, and the walls being insulators means charge can't leak outside through the walls either.

Comment: Amazing explanation in edit brother! Can you also clarify the second part of my question? Will the charge of the powder (not the field, which we can understand will emanate out of the disk) leak out of the disk? Check my edit for what "disk" is. Just a very flat cylinder, made of insulator material, with stuffed in charged powder. Normally, the charged powder would be exposed to air, and it would lose its charge over some time. Will being isolated from air and conducting materials keep it charged for longer?