# Doubt regarding spherical capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, conductors

Suppose we have a hollow conducting sphere having a charge Q residing on it's surface. Then we take another such sphere which is bigger than the one mentioned before and surround the smaller one with it,
**would this cause the charge on the inner sphere to appear on the outer surface of the bigger sphere?**

If yes, then how can a spherical capacitor even work if all the charge on the inner sphere goes to the outer sphere's outside surface

I have added an image below for reference

[image]

Comment: This problem is similar to [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758903/electric-field-inside-conductor-with-a-cavity/758910#758910). I want to know (1) whether the size of the outer conductor is infinite or finite, and (2) whether the outer conductor is grounded (i.e. electric charges are supplied into the outer conductor from the ground, and the resultant electric potential of the outer conductor is zero).

Answer (score 0):

> would this cause the charge on the inner sphere to appear on the outer surface of the bigger sphere?

A charge equal to the charge on the inner sphere would appear on the outer surface of the surrounding sphere, but not the actual same charge. The inner sphere would retain its charge, and an equal-but-opposite charge would appear on the inner surface of the outer sphere.

> how can a spherical capacitor even work if all the charge on the inner sphere goes to the outer sphere's outside surface

To make a capacitor "work" (that is, to do anything useful with it) we have to connect both of its "plates" (in this case, we have two spherical plates) to some other circuit. When we  make that connection we can now move charge on and off of the plates, producing currents in the connected circuit.

The charge on the outer surface of the outer plate is not particularly relevant to this effect. And in fact that charge may go away if we, for example, connect the outer plate (sphere) to the local ground potential.

Comment: Thank you! Though I have another query, how would there exist a potential difference between the two spheres of the capacitor considering that the electric field inside a conductor must be zero in electrostatic conditions (the outer sphere is enclosing the inner one)?

Comment: @NewUser25, the electric field between the two spheres is not 0. If you put a gaussian surface in the gap between the two spheres, it encloses the inner sphere's charge, but not the outer sphere's charge, so there will be nonzero flux through that surface.

Answer (score 0):

*. . . . . would this cause the charge on the inner sphere to appear on the outer surface of the bigger sphere?*

The positive charge which appears on the outside of the shell is charge induced by the positive charge on the sphere with the positive and negative charges being of equal magnitude.
There is also an equal magnitude of negative charge induced on the inside of the shell making the outer shell electrically neutral.

So the positive charge on the sphere does not move, it cannot because the region between the sphere and the shell is an insulator.

Earthing the shell will result in the positive charges which were on its outer surface moving to the earth leaving the shell negatively charged.